# ASP.net MVC Authorize attribute not working on action when controller has AllowAnonymous attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-identity

I have asp.net MVC5 project
I allowed all actions in Home controller anonymously
but now the requirement is to prevent 2 actions and make them accessible only if user is logged in.
below code is not working means showing jobapply page without login

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using myproject.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Configuration;

namespace myproject.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous] /************Controller level AllowAnonymous************/
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public HomeController()
        {
             //code
        }

        [Authorize]/***********************this is not working*************/
        public ActionResult Jobapply(int id)
        { 
        return View();
        }


    [Authorize]/***********************this is not working*************/
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Jobapply(VacancyApplication vacancyApp)
    {
        return View();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: add `[AllowAnonymous]` to the functions that dont need authorization.

Comment: If you are applying the `Authorize` attribute to Actions then there is no need to apply the `AllowAnonymous` attribute to the Controller.

Comment: controller has 30 actions, only 2 are restricted

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the [Authorize] Attribute at the controller level and individually allow the actions which you want to allow without authorization apply [AllowAnonymous] attribute on that particular actions.